# How to mutate columns by position instead of specifying the names

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following dataframe in R

```
data <- structure(list(Category = c("Food", "Alcoholic B\\&T", "Clothing", 
"Housing", "Furnishings", "Health", "Transport", "Communication", 
"Recreation", "Education", "Hotels", "Miscellaneous", "All items"
), Weight = c(" 16.4", " 12.6", "  3.0", " 28.4", "  5.5", "  2.0", 
" 14.3", "  3.8", "  3.6", "  3.6", "  1.4", "  5.4", "100.0"
), `*Jul 2023` = c("10.5", " 6.9", " 1.8", " 2.7", " 7.0", " 4.1", 
"-2.5", " 0.6", " 9.9", " 3.8", " 5.3", " 5.6", " 4.5"), `*Aug 2023` = c("10.5", 
" 6.9", " 1.2", " 2.4", " 6.9", " 4.1", "-2.4", " 1.0", " 9.6", 
" 3.8", " 5.0", " 5.3", " 4.5"), `*Sep 2023` = c("10.3", " 6.6", 
" 1.4", " 2.3", " 6.3", " 3.9", "-0.8", " 0.6", " 9.4", " 3.8", 
" 4.8", " 4.9", " 4.6"), `*Oct 2023` = c("11.5", " 6.6", " 1.1", 
" 2.2", " 6.1", " 3.2", "-0.8", " 0.9", " 9.7", " 3.8", " 4.6", 
" 4.9", " 4.7"), `**Aug 2023` = c("10.1", " 6.9", " 1.2", " 2.8", 
" 6.9", " 4.1", "-2.7", " 1.0", " 9.6", " 3.8", " 5.0", " 5.3", 
" 4.4"), `**Sep 2023` = c("10.4", " 6.6", " 1.4", " 2.6", " 6.3", 
" 3.9", "-1.1", " 0.6", " 9.4", " 3.8", " 4.8", " 4.9", " 4.6"
), `**Oct 2023` = c("11.6", " 6.6", " 1.1", " 2.5", " 6.1", " 3.2", 
"-1.1", " 0.9", " 9.7", " 3.8", " 4.6", " 4.9", " 4.8")), row.names = c(NA, 
-13L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I would like to mutate the last three columns  (7:9 in my dataframe) depending on whether they're equal to their corresponding columns (4:6 in my dataframe) as I've done below. I'm able to do this by specifying the column names (e.g `` `**Aug 2023` == `*Aug 2023` ``), but is there a way to write this dynamically (`e.g 7th column in my dataframe == 4th column in my dataframe`    instead?

```
library(tidyverse)

data %>% 
  mutate(`**Aug 2023` = cell_spec(`**Aug 2023`, background = ifelse(`**Aug 2023`==`*Aug 2023`, 'white', '#c7af76')),
         `**Sep 2023` = cell_spec(`**Sep 2023`, background = ifelse(`**Sep 2023`==`*Sep 2023`, 'white', '#c7af76')),
         `**Oct 2023` = cell_spec(`**Oct 2023`, background = ifelse(`**Oct 2023`==`*Oct 2023`, 'white', '#c7af76')))
```

Comment: you can use across! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a helper function that can pull out a column based on an offset

```
col_offset <- function(offset) {
  colnames <- names(cur_data())
  curcol <- cur_column()
  idx <- which(curcol==colnames) + offset
  col <- ifelse(idx < 1 | idx > length(colnames), NA, colnames[idx])
  cur_data()[[col]]
}
```

We use `cur_data()` and `cur_column()` to figure out where we are. This will only work in the context of a dplyr change using `across()`. We can then apply it to the data using

```
data %>%
  mutate(across(7:9, ~cell_spec(.x, background=ifelse(.x == col_offset(-3), "white", "#c7af76"))))
```

We we apply this function to columns 7-9 and we use `col_offset(-3)` to get the values of the column three places to the left.

I'm not sure where `cell_spec` comes from but I tested with

```
cell_spec <- function(x, background) {
  paste0(x, " -bg- ", background)
}
```

and it seemed to work just fine

Answer (score 1):

Please try the code

```r
library(kableExtra)
data2 <- data %>% 
  mutate(across(c(`**Aug 2023`,`**Sep 2023`,`**Oct 2023`), 
                ~ cell_spec(cur_column(), background = ifelse(get(cur_column())==get(str_remove(cur_column(),'^\\*')), 'white', '#c7af76'))
                )
         )
```

<sup>Created on 2023-08-16 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

```r
# A tibble: 13 × 9
   Category       Weight `*Jul 2023` `*Aug 2023` `*Sep 2023` `*Oct 2023`
   <chr>          <chr>  <chr>       <chr>       <chr>       <chr>      
 1 "Food"         " 16.… "10.5"      "10.5"      "10.3"      "11.5"     
 2 "Alcoholic B\… " 12.… " 6.9"      " 6.9"      " 6.6"      " 6.6"     
 3 "Clothing"     "  3.… " 1.8"      " 1.2"      " 1.4"      " 1.1"     
 4 "Housing"      " 28.… " 2.7"      " 2.4"      " 2.3"      " 2.2"     
 5 "Furnishings"  "  5.… " 7.0"      " 6.9"      " 6.3"      " 6.1"     
 6 "Health"       "  2.… " 4.1"      " 4.1"      " 3.9"      " 3.2"     
 7 "Transport"    " 14.… "-2.5"      "-2.4"      "-0.8"      "-0.8"     
 8 "Communicatio… "  3.… " 0.6"      " 1.0"      " 0.6"      " 0.9"     
 9 "Recreation"   "  3.… " 9.9"      " 9.6"      " 9.4"      " 9.7"     
10 "Education"    "  3.… " 3.8"      " 3.8"      " 3.8"      " 3.8"     
11 "Hotels"       "  1.… " 5.3"      " 5.0"      " 4.8"      " 4.6"     
12 "Miscellaneou… "  5.… " 5.6"      " 5.3"      " 4.9"      " 4.9"     
13 "All items"    "100.… " 4.5"      " 4.5"      " 4.6"      " 4.7"     
# ℹ 3 more variables: `**Aug 2023` <chr>, `**Sep 2023` <chr>,
#   `**Oct 2023` <chr>
```